# PlatformNotSupportedException when trying to create a TransactionScope with multiple DbContext with same connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have multiple DbContext in the same ASP.NET Core website with Entity Framework Core and I want to create a transaction so that if SaveChanges fails in one context any changes on the other contexts are rolled back. These DbContext all have the same connection string, therefore they are connected to the same database.

However, when I try to create a TransactionScope, I get a PlatformNotSupportedException that says distributed transactions are not supported. But all DbContext are connected to the same database! Is there any way to create a TransactionScope with multiple DbContext connected to the same database without creating a distributed transaction?